# How to store an array of an unknown amount of strings of unknown length from input?

Tags: c, valgrind, c89

I have trouble with storing strings in an array from input. I want to store it from input ending with EOF and be able to store any amount of strings of any length. Here is my code:

```
char **list = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
char c = getchar();
int i, j, count = 0;
int size = 0;
char * string = NULL
while (c != EOF)
{
    size = 0;
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        string = (char*)realloc(string,size+1); //line 210
        string[size] = c;
        size++;
        c = getchar();
    }
    list = (char**)realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(char*));
    list[count] = string;
    ++count;
    string = NULL;
    c = getchar();
}
for (j = 0; j < count; ++j) //trying to print out all the strings
{
    printf("%s\n", list[j]); //line 237
}
free(string);
free(list);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I know I should also be testing whether all the allocs where successful, but that is not my issue right now. The program works properly when compiled with gcc -Wall -pedantic, but valgrind gives the following errors:

```
==2601== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2601== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2601== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2601== Command: ./a.out -g
==2601== 
asd
dsa
==2601== Invalid read of size 1
==2601==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2601==    by 0x4EA95DB: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==2601==    by 0x4008E8: main (testing.c:237)
==2601==  Address 0x52035c3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2601==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2601==    by 0x40080D: main (testing.c:210)
==2601== 
asd
dsa
==2601== 
==2601== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2601==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 4 blocks
==2601==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 10 frees, 2,101 bytes allocated
==2601== 
==2601== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2601==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 4 blocks
==2601==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2601==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2601==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2601==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2601== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2601== 
==2601== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2601== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Also, after `char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` you set `string = NULL;` before passing `string` to `realloc`. Thus throwing away the previous allocation and any content (even if it *was* only one byte!).

Comment: `list[count] = string;` is enough overwrites the memory allocated in `list[count] = malloc();`.

Comment: Addressed all the comments and edited the code, the same problem persists still. @j

Comment: Why have you changed the code? Now nobody will trust this is your *actual* code, until you post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All the error messages point to the `main` function, which you didn't provide.

Comment: This is the main function.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand, you can see the edits to see how the code has changed, which is also supported by my comment alerting of the changes. Also, thank you, I guess! Bottom line: the improvements didn't work for valgrind.

Comment: Please highlight lines 210 and 237.

Comment: @shiftingsand this site is not an online tutorial where your code shifts and modifies according to comments. Having had memory leaks pointed out I suggest you go away and revise your code, have a good think about it, come back later and ask another question it you still have problems.

Comment: @RaymondChen Lines highlighted.

Comment: getchar() returns an int and EOF is an int.  You cannot use a char for c.

Comment: You realloc the string after putting a pointer to it in the list. (Because you don't reset the `string` after each iteration.) Stepping through the code with a debugger would have helped find that issue.

Comment: @RaymondChen-- I believe that OP has fixed this particular issue in the code from the question. Perhaps you are looking at the earlier version of the question? Of course, this is one reason why posters should not modify the code of their questions as issues are pointed out by commenters!

Comment: All those `int`s should be `size_t`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yeah, I didn't think that through very much. I am still a noob around here, so forgive my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `free`ing `string` at the end of the program, you need to free the memory allocated for each of the strings that you read:

```
for (j = 0; j < count; j++)    
        free(list[j]);
free(list);
```

To fix the `"Invalid read of size 1"` error, you need to change:

```
string = realloc(string,size+2);
```

You are using `size` as the index for `string`, so you need to increment this value before adding a space for the '\0' in the allocation. Better variable names would have helped avoid this issue. Consider changing `size` to `index`.

Note also that you need `c` to be an `int` in order to store the `EOF` character, so change:

```
int c = getchar();
```

Also, this code is failing to terminate the strings with a `NUL`. You need to add:

```
...
string[size] = '\0';    // NUL terminate string

list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
...
```

When you initialize `list` at the beginning of the program, there is no need to allocate space yet, and you just end up `realloc`ing it anyway, so:

```
char **list = NULL;
```

And notice that I removed the casts from the calls to `malloc()` and `realloc()`. These are not needed in C, and mostly serve to clutter the code. Similarly, instead of using `sizeof(char*)` here, I used `sizeof(*list)`, which is less error-prone and much more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the `free`ing problem, but the `'Invalid read` problem persists.

Comment: @shiftingsand-- I added some more comments about other issues and mistakes in your code.